# Getting an empty response when fetching data using aiohttp

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to fetch some data from fantasy premier league API. It was very straight forward using the `requests` library in python. [Snippet 1]

However, when trying to fetch the same data using `asyncio` and `aiohttp`, I am getting an empty response even though the status is 200. Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

I was able to use `aiohttp` to fetch json data from a private API. So, it does not look like am issue with my configuration.

I am using python 3.7.9.

Using requests

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/")
response.json()
```

Using asyncio and aiohttp

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/') as resp:
            return await resp.json()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by specifying the `User-Agent` in the header.

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'xyz'}
async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(
            'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/',
            headers=headers
        ) as resp:
            return await resp.json()

await main()
```